# Calendar app does not refresh on lock screen - Lumia 720

Tags: lock-screen

I have a Lumia 720 Phone, and the Calendar app does not refresh on the lock screen. Moreover it shows an appointment which was the first entry of the week but is has been deleted long ago. I tried to change the detailed app to something else, lock the phone and change it back again, but it's still the same. Please help what else could be done?

Answer (score 3):

I have just had the same problem on my 830. 
Rectified by pinning to the start page.
Hope this helps.
Now looking for a suitable app to show multiple events on lock screen and homepage.